# Extract Decimal Number from String in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We have a text cell that always say

"Some items ###.## australian dollars abcdefg"

So we always know there is "australian dollars" in the string. But numbers can be very small like .01 or very big like 1,000.33

How do we extract the numbers complete with decimal in simplest way?

Comment: You mean to say that if Cell `A1` has `$125.00` then you want in `B1` `125.00` only!!

Comment: Yes but in my cell there is no $, just 250.00 australian dollars. I want 250.00 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are interested in just the "word" in front of "Australian dollars". We can [extract the last word of a string](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-word) using:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(text," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

So we just need to combine that with a `LEFT` function, because the "last" word we need would always sits in front of "Australian Dollars", according to your explaination. Combined with som `TRIM` it would come down to:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("australian dollars",A1)-1))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

In an example of mixed type of strings we get:

[image]

---

Another option would be to look into power query. But when I just tried it, it does take a fair bit of steps so I think the quickest way would be using the formula.

Answer (score 2):

*You may try this when Number is followed by Text string:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `B2`, fill it down.

  ```
   =LEFT(A2,SUM(LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},""))))
  ```

**N.B.** This method handles any length of characters after the Number.

## Edited:

*Following Formula can be used if Number is wrapped with Text string in Cell.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `I45`:

  ```
   =LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(MID(H45,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, $H45&"1023456789")),999),ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))))
  ```

*Where,*

- `LOOKUP(9.9E+307,` find the largest value.
- `INDIRECT`creates reference, never changes even when value in cells are inserted or deleted.

**N.B.** This method handles any length of characters after & before Number.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

if the phrase "australian dollars" does not change, you can use below formula

```
B2= Value(Left(A1,Len(A1)-19))
```

and format the `B2` Cell as you like